# Three.js raycaster to intersect only specified part of shape

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to get an intersection using raycaster only with vertices of a geometry and not with all the geometry shape. I wrote this code but nothing happen if I click on vertice setted.

```
         function onDocumentMouseClick(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            mouse2D.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse2D.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster = projector.pickingRay(mouse2D.clone(), camera);

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects[0].geometry.vertices[0]);// I want intersection only with vertices

            if (intersects.length > 0) {

                console.log("ok");}
```

Comment: Raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, recursive) expects an array of objects... so you can't use a single vertex as the parameter. If you want to optimize for fewer vertices I guess you'd have to create objects with just the vertices you want to test. I think you need to use objects because otherwise the geometry vertices would not be transformed correctly.

Comment: You had a great idea thanks. How can I know after intersection happened which vertice was intersected? @pixelmike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to pass an array of objects to `raycaster.intersectObjects`, as suggested by `pixelmike`:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([objects[0]])
```

You can't get the vertex of the intersection per se, but you can get the `face` for each intersection:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    if ( intersect.face == myTargetFace ) {
        console.log( "ok" );
    }
}
```

If you really want the particular object to only check for intersections with a particular subset of faces, you could override the `raycast` method of that object (a la https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Mesh.js#L56-L340 ) to only search those faces.

three.js r68